# how to achieve following overlay while keeping it responsive

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to achieve white overlay that can be seen above. image behind it is a slideshow and I need to show little bit of it with that triangle cut out in the middle, I'm trying to figure out a way of how to achieve this with pseudo elements while keeping solution responsive at the same time, but cant seem to find a way. I was also thinking about using multiple backgrounds, but am not sure how to make one of them in the centre and other two on the sides.

```
<div id="slideshow"></div>
```

Above is markup for slideshow at the moment (slides appear as background images of this div, it is absolutely positioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing some pseudo class before and afters on the center container, you can create CSS triangles using CSS borders.

See this for CSS triangles : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Technically you wouldn't need to use the before/after for the containers but I used it here anyways to keep the mark-up clean.

Next using some positioning and some width calculations, I set the two containers (left and right) to width 40% which leaves me 20% to play around with for the center section.

Lastly using, vw units, I set the border-left and border-right sizes to be 10vw. This is important because it basically allows the borders to be responsive based on the viewport width as long as the slideshow is full width.

See the JSFiddle here (Updated) : https://jsfiddle.net/x117ss0q/4/

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow-overlay-wrapper">
        <div class="slideshow-overlay left"></div>
        <div class="slideshow-overlay-center"></div>
        <div class="slideshow-overlay right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    #slideshow{
    background-color: #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}
.slideshow-overlay-wrapper {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.slideshow-overlay {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
}
.slideshow-overlay-center {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.slideshow-overlay-center:after {
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid #FFF;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.slideshow-overlay-center:before {
    content: '';
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid #FFF;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to keep center triangle at fixed width? What I meant by responsive is to ensure that left and right sides always go and occupy needed width.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting with that to get it fully responsive. I think it may be possible with a wrapping container around the three overlays and utilizing display table and table-cell